# Reliably find quasi_quotations implementations

Tags: swi-prolog, swi-prolog-for-sharing

How to find which quasi_quotations implementations are available in a given SWI-Prolog, installed from source, or a locally installed SWISH ?
I tried to search for the key implementation 
`quasi_quotation_syntax` or `quasi_quotation`, and found just the `R` handler in `swish/pack/rserve_client` and the `html` handler in `packages/http/html_quasiquotations.pl`.
I think, there are a lot more ready to use after a basic SWISH installation.